# inserting different strings in matlab gui's html texts

Tags: html, matlab

I'm not very good with html so I'd like some help with the html component in matlab.

So I have a matlab gui, and I inserted an html object to display static text with multiple colors.  Here's what I have so far,

```
s = '<html><font color="#2E9AFE"><b>testing123</b></font><font color="#F5A9BC"><b> test234</b></font></html>';
h = javacomponent(javax.swing.JLabel(s), [10,10,150,100]);
```

My question is, is it possible for me to change the strings being displayed to a variable instead of a static text, in similar ways to sprintf function in Matlab?

Thank you in advance for any help you can give. =)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure to understand your question very well but it seems obvious that you can indeed use `sprintf` to define `s` instead of a static definition. Do you want to change the content of the `JLabel` dynamically ?

Comment: Actually that's exactly what I need.  I can't believe I didn't think of it before.  Thank you very much.